# PHP display problem?

Tags: php

For some reason when an array has for example, four values it will display all four values four times I just want the values to be displayed one time.

How can I fix this problem? Note the first echo works perfectly.

Here is the code.

```
if (count($array) == 1){
    echo $array[$x] . " one value has been entered";
} else {
    echo implode(", ", $array) ." you entered more then one value;

}
```

Comment: For one thing you're missing closing quotes before the `;` in the `else` block.

Comment: it happened when I posted the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$x` obviously isn't the index of the first element of the array. Use the correct index. Or if you don't know what it is, just use [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
if (count($array) == 1) {
  echo reset($array) . ' one value has been entered';
} else {
  echo implode(', ', $array) . ' you entered more than one value';
}
```

It might be helpful to dump the array to see what it actually contains:

```
print_r($array);
```

Comment: I fail to see how. To put it another way: what's happening? Or another: I suspect you have something else going awry.

Comment: let say the array has two value apple and pear it will display each value twice apple pear apple pear.

Comment: If so it's doing that with code you haven't presented here so, like I said, you've got something else going on. Perhaps you're not building/seeding $array correctly. Perhaps this section of code is being called more than once. Something like that.

Comment: Your comment made me take a second look at my code which helped me solve my own question.

Answer (score 0):

$x is not set in your code or just meaningless. If you have just one array item you can print it with the simple `echo $array[0];`